# how to migrate git hub project to sub version

Tags: spring, maven, svn, github

I have a spring maven project in git hub. Due to some reasons, I need to sift it to local subversion server. 
I have searched but not getting any suitable guide to do so.

Can anybody help or give some tips?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Found few way around for above problem:

```
 Download your git hub project   
 Unzip the zip file   
 Enable show hidden file from your folder settings   
 From the project file , search with "*git*"   
 You will find .git and .gitignore   
 delete these files   
 Import it to your SVN repositories
```

That's it.

Comment: The answer depends on whether you need history